# jQuery scrollTop() not working on 'body' element in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, scroll

I do not understand why the scrollTop() jquery function is not working on the 'body' element on Firefox.

```
$('body').scrollTop(0);
```

I fixed my issue using:

```
$(window).scrollTop(0);
```

However according to the jquery documentation scrollTop() is supposed to work on all elements like in this example:

```
$( "div.demo" ).scrollTop( 300 );
```

I have also tested with 'nav' and 'main' but it is not working either.

Comment: Have you tried `$("body, html").scrollTop(0);`?

Comment: For browser window scrolling only option is $(window), on other elements scrollTop is working only if their parent element has scrollbar.

Comment: I have tested in chrome and scrollTop() with 'body' selector is working perfectly. It seems to be a Firefox issue.

Comment: Indeed $("body, html").scrollTop(0) is working also in firefox. So the question is: why is it necessary to specify a context for the selector in firefox but not in chrome?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Scroll**

`$(window).scrollTop(0);` seems to be supported by all browsers IE9+ (maybe IE8 but I don't test on that any more).

**Animated Scroll**

If you want to animate a scroll, jQuery returns an error if using the `window` object (1.11.2 tested). Instead, to animate a scroll, it's best to use both `html` and `body` to cover engines which utilise either one. So:

`$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0},500);` will scroll to the top of the browser in half a second.

**Scroll Position**

You cannot use `$('html,body').scrollTop()` to find the current scroll position of the page - at least Chrome doesn't support this (always returns 0). Instead, to consistently find the scroll position of a page, it's necessary to use `$(window).scrollTop();`.

Comment: Your last paragraph was life-saving.

Answer (score 13):

Use `window` if you want consistency between browsers.

```
$(window).scrollTop();
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

your div to scroll:

```
<div id="top"></div>
```

and scroll top js:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#top').offset().top},'slow');
```

Comment: Thank you but I do not want to animate the scrolling. I was able to scroll to the top using `$(window).scrollTop(0)` or `$("body, html").scrollTop(0)` but it does not explain why `$("body").scrollTop(0)` is not working in Firefox while it does in Chrome.

Comment: @jthe firefox has the overflow at html-level and not body-level as the webkit based browser

Comment: I was seeing something similar and realized that I wasn't fully reloading the document. Once I placed the cursor in the location bar and pressed enter, it worked. Just a thought- good luck.

Comment: @Marcus If you query `overflow` on `html` and `body` in both browsers they return `visible`

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple Code , working 100%

```
$('body, html').scrollTop(0);
```