# Slideshow buttons and $.backstretch plugin not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For some reason the arrow buttons (which scroll the body element left and right are not working at all in IE(8 or 11 and possibly other versions) and some of the links on the left (like Company) are not working sometimes (not loading the background images)

http://henrybuiltfurniture.com/

How can I fix these issues?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .limiter * {
                transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
                -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            }
            body{
                font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
                font-weight: 300;
            }
            html, body{
                height:100%;
            }
            body{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                overflow:hidden;
                background-color:black;
            }
            img{
                border:0;
            }
            .wide{
                width:5000px;
                height:100%;
                overflow: hidden;
                z-index: 1;
                display:none;
            }
            .wide div.limiter{
                overflow: hidden;
                position: absolute;
            }
            .wide .limiter .cont{
                position: relative;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .wide .limiter .data{
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 60%;
                height: 60%;
                padding: 110px 25% 20% 20%;
                font-size: 35px;
                color: white;
            }
            .wide .limiter .data div{
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                text-align: left;
            }
            .wide .limiter .data div a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
            }
            .wide .limiter .data div a:hover{
                color:#666;
            }
            body { 
                width: 8000px; 
            }
            .menu{
                width: 150px;
                position: fixed;
                left: -150px;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 5;
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
            }
            .menu .logo{
                width:100px;
                height:100px;
            }
            .menu ul{
                list-style: none;
            }
            .menu li{
                list-style: none;
            }
            .menu li a{
                color:#FFF;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            .menu li a.active{
                color:#CCC;
            }
            .menu li a:hover{
                color:#CFCFCF;
            }
            .loading{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 0;
                background-color: black;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                display:none;
            }
            .loading .wrap{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position: relative;
            }
            .loading .center{
                margin: auto;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                width: 800px;
                left: 50%;
                margin-top: -100px;
                margin-left: -400px;
                height: 200px;
                text-align: center;
                color:#999;
            }
            .loading .navhint{
                font-size: 12px;
                margin-top:0px;
                margin-bottom: 100px;
                color:#999;
                position: relative;
                top:-30px;
            }
            .loading .scroll{
                font-size: 80px;
            }
            .loading .loadhint{
                font-size: 20px;
            }
            .loadingBar{
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                height: 15px;
                width: 0px;
                background-color: #999;
            }
            .caption{
                position: fixed;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 60px;
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
                display: none;
            }
            .caption .logo{
                float:left;
                height:40px;
                width:150px;
                text-align: left;
                position: relative;
                top:0px;
            }
            .caption .logo img{
                border:0;
                width:150px;
                height:60px;
            }
            .slidehint{
                width:100%;
                height:10px;
            }
            .text{
                float:left;
                width:60%;
                height:40px;
                font-size: 11px;
                margin-left:30px;
                position: relative;
            }
            .textbottom{
                position: absolute;
                width:100%;
                bottom: 3;
                color: #e0e0e0;
                font-size: 11px;
            }
            .buttons{
                width:120px;
                float:right;
                height:40px;
                position:relative;
                top:-3px;
                margin-right: 30px;
            }
            .buttons .left{
                float:left;
                display: none;
            }
            .buttons .left:hover{
                cursor: pointer;
                opacity: 0.7;
            }
            .buttons .right{
                display:none;               float:right;
            }
            .buttons .right:hover{
                cursor: pointer;
                opacity: 0.7;
            }
            .menubar{
                display: none;
                position: fixed;
                left: 60px;
                top: 50%;
                margin-top: -72px;
                z-index: 3;
            }
            .menubar img{
                height: 32px;
                width: 32px;
            }
            .br{
                height: 15px;
                width: 20px;
            }
            .data div{
                font-size: 24px;
            }
        </style>

        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
        <script>
            var ww;
            var wh;

            var oldviewing = 0;
            var viewing = 1;

            var scrolling = 0;
            var scrolldir = 0;
            var blockdelta = false;

            var menu = 0;

            var images = 1;
            var loaded = false;

            var defCaption;
            var curCaption;
            var captions = [];

                var already_visited = false;            

            window.onresize = function(){
                ww = $(window).width()+2;
                wh = $(window).height();

                resizeImages();
            }

            $(document).ready(function(){

                document.ontouchmove = function(e){ 
                    e.preventDefault(); 
                }


                    $(".menu").css({left:"0px"});
                    $(".menubar").css({visibility:"none"});


                if(!(/Mobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && !/ipad/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )){
                    $(".mobile_css").html("");
                }

                //window properties
                ww = $(window).width()+2;
                wh = $(window).height();

                defCaption = "";
                curCaption = defCaption;


captions[1] = "";

                if(captions[1]){
                    curCaption = captions[1];
                    $(".textbottom").html(captions[1]);
                }else{
                    curCaption = defCaption;
                }

                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".loading").fadeIn(500);
                }, 500)

                setInterval(function(){

                    if(scrolling && scrolldir != 2 && scrolldir != 0){
                        if(scrolldir == -1){
                            prev();
                        }else if(scrolldir == 1){
                            next();
                        }
                        scrolling = 0;
                    }

                    if(loaded == false && $("body").scrollLeft() != 0){
                        $("body").scrollLeft(0);
                    }
                }, .05);

                $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
                    if(scrolldir == 2){
                        blockdelta = true;
                    }else if(blockdelta == true){
                        if(Math.abs(deltaX) <= 10 && Math.abs(deltaY) <= 1){
                            blockdelta = false;
                        }
                    }

                    if(blockdelta == true){
                        deltaX = 0;
                        deltaY = 0;
                    }

                    if(Math.abs(deltaX) > 10){
                        if(scrolldir != 2){
                            scrolling = 1;
                            scrolldir = 1;
                            if(event.deltaX < 0){
                                scrolldir = -1
                            }
                        }
                    }else if(Math.abs(deltaY) > 1){
                        if(scrolldir != 2){
                            scrolling = 1;
                            scrolldir = 1;
                            if(event.deltaY < 0){
                                scrolldir = -1
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    event.preventDefault();
                });

                $(".caption .buttons .right").click(function(){
                    next();
                });

                $(".caption .buttons .left").click(function(){
                    prev();
                });
            });

            function changeCaption(i){
                if(captions[i]){
                    $(".textbottom").fadeOut(300, function(){
                        $(".textbottom").html(captions[i]);
                        $(".textbottom").fadeIn(300);
                    });
                }else if(curCaption != defCaption){
                    $(".textbottom").fadeOut(300, function(){
                        $(".textbottom").html(defCaption);
                        $(".textbottom").fadeIn(300);
                    });
                }
            }

            function resizeImages(){

                $('body')[0].scrollLeft = ww*(viewing-1);

                for(i=1; i<=images; i++){
                    //$("html")[0].scrollLeft(viewing*ww);

                    //picture properties
                    pw = $("#img"+i)[0].width;
                    ph = $("#img"+i)[0].height;
                    //size calculation
                    ph = (ww/pw)*ph;
                    pw = ww;

                    if(ph < wh){
                        pw = (wh/ph)*pw;
                        ph = wh;
                    }

                    //image resizage
                    $("#img"+i).css({width:pw, height:ph, position:"absolute", top:Math.round(-1*(wh - (wh/ph)*wh)/2), left:Math.round(-1*(ww - (ww/pw)*ww)/2)});
                    $("#limiter"+i).css({width:ww, height:wh, position:"absolute", left:(i-1)*ww});

                    $(".wide").css({width:images*ww, height:wh});
                }
            }

            var total = 0;

            function bump(){
                $('body')[0].scrollLeft = 0;

                goal = images;

                total++;
                if(already_visited){
                    $(".load").html("( loading "+total+" of "+images+" images ... )");
                    resizeImages();
                    $(".center").hide()
                    $(".wide").show();
                    $(".caption").show();
                    $(".menubar").show();
                    loaded = true;
                }else{
                    $(".load").html("( loading "+total+" of "+images+" images ... )");
                    $(".loadingBar").animate({width: total*$(window).width() / images}, 200, function(){
                        if(total >= goal){
                            resizeImages();
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $(".center").fadeOut(700, function(){
                                    $(".wide").fadeIn(500);
                                    $(".caption").fadeIn(500);
                                    $(".menubar").fadeIn(500);
                                });
                                loaded = true;

                                setTimeout(function(){

                                }, 500);
                            }, 800);
                        }
                    });
                }


            }

            var image_change_speed = 600;

            function next(){

                if(viewing < images){
                    scrolldir = 2;
                    changeCaption(viewing+1);
                    $('body').animate({scrollLeft: $("#limiter"+(viewing+1)).css("left")}, image_change_speed, 'easeOutCirc', function() { 

                        scrolldir = 0;
                        viewing++;

                        if(viewing >= images){
                            $(".caption .buttons .right").fadeOut(300);
                        }else{
                            if($(".caption .buttons .right").css("display") == "none"){
                                $(".caption .buttons .right").fadeIn(300);
                            }
                        }

                        if(viewing <= 1){
                            $(".caption .buttons .left").fadeOut(300);
                        }else{
                            if($(".caption .buttons .left").css("display") == "none"){
                                $(".caption .buttons .left").fadeIn(300);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            function prev(){

                if(viewing > 1){
                    scrolldir = 2;
                    changeCaption(viewing-1);
                    $('body').animate({scrollLeft: $("#limiter"+(viewing-1)).css("left")}, image_change_speed, 'easeOutCirc', function() { 
                        scrolldir = 0;
                        viewing--;

                        if(viewing <= 1){
                            $(".caption .buttons .left").fadeOut(300);
                        }else{
                            if($(".caption .buttons .left").css("display") == "none"){
                                $(".caption .buttons .left").fadeIn(300);
                            }
                        }

                        if(viewing >= images){
                            $(".caption .buttons .right").fadeOut(300);
                        }else{
                            if($(".caption .buttons .right").css("display") == "none"){
                                $(".caption .buttons .right").fadeIn(300);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="loading">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="center">
                                        <div class="scroll">Home</div>
                                        <div class="load">( loading 0 of 1 images ... )</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="loadingBar"></div>
        </div>
                <div class="menu">
            <div class="logo">

            </div>
            <ul>

                <li><a  href="index.php?p=chair">Chair 2</a></li>

                <li><a  href="index.php?p=desk">Desk</a></li>
                                <li><div class="br"></div></li>

                <li><a  href="index.php?p=wave-stool">Wave Stool</a></li>
                                <li><div class="br"></div></li>

                <li><a  href="index.php?p=steel-table-4">Steel Table 4</a></li>

                <li><a  href="index.php?p=steel-table-5">Storage Table</a></li>
                                <li><div class="br"></div></li>

                <li><a  href="index.php?p=wood-table-5">Wood Table 5</a></li>

                <li><a  href="index.php?p=wood-table-6">Wood Table 6</a></li>
                                <li><div class="br"></div></li>

                <li><a  href="index.php?p=wave-bench">Wave Bench</a></li>

                <li><a  href="index.php?p=scoop-bench">Scoop Bench</a></li>
                                <li><div class="br"></div></li>

                <li><a  href="index.php?p=hb-kitchens">HB Kitchens</a></li>

                <li><a  href="index.php?p=hb-opencase">HB Opencase</a></li>
                                <li><div class="br"></div></li>

                    <li><a href="archive.php">Image Archive</a></li>
                    <br class="mobile_br" />
                    <br />


                <li><a  class="active" href="index.php?p=home"><img src="images/home.png" /></a></li>

                <li><a  href="index.php?p=company">The Company</a></li>

                <li><a  href="index.php?p=quality">Quality</a></li>

                <li><a  href="index.php?p=contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="wide">
                        <div id="limiter1" class="limiter">
                <div class="cont">
                    <img src="images/1_1.jpg" id="img1" alt="img1" onload="bump();" class="slideimage"/>
                    <div class="data">
                        <div>
                                                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="http://henrybuilt.com">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="henrybuilt"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slidehint">

            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <div class="textbottom">
                                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <div class="left">
                    <img src="images/lArrow.png" alt="left"/>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <img src="images/rArrow.png" alt="right"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="mobile_css">
            <style>
                .br{
                    height: 5px;
                }
                .wide .limiter .data{
                    font-size: 1em;
                }
                .wide .limiter .data div{
                    position: relative;
                    top: -50px;
                }
                .caption{
                    height: 10%;
                    min-height: 80px;
                }
                .buttons{
                    width:300px;
                    height:100%;
                    width: auto;
                }
                .buttons img{
                    height: 80%;
                }
                .caption .logo, .caption .logo img{
                    height: 100%;
                    width: auto;
                }
                .caption .logo{
                    width: auto;
                }
                .text{
                    display: none;
                }
                .menubar{
                    display: none;
                    position: fixed;
                    left: 60px;
                    top: 50%;
                    margin-top: -72px;
                    z-index: 3;
                }
                .menubar img{
                    height: 100px;
                    width: 100px;
                }
                .menu{
                    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
                }
                .menu .logo{
                    width:100px;
                    height:0px;
                }
                .menu li a{
                    position: relative;
                    top: -10px;
                    font-size: 0.9em
                }
                .menu ul{
                    margin-left: -20px;
                }
                .data div{
                    font-size: 36px;
                }
                .mobile_br{
                    display: none;
                }
            </style>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't work in firefox, too...

Answer (score 0):

I think i have solution. Thanks to this post and answers! [jQuery scrollTop() not working on 'body' element in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556752/jquery-scrolltop-not-working-on-body-element-in-firefox)

So, add $('html,body') as selector in your prev() and next() functions...

Function next() ->
line 475:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollLeft: $("#limiter"+(viewing+1)).css("....
```

Function prev()

line 504:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollLeft: $("#limiter"+(viewing-1)).cs....
```

Comment: Please add the code you changed to your answer. Or are you saying the live site is working now?

Comment: Okay this kind of fixed it - using the comma with both elements causes the image to scroll twice, but if you detect which browser is in use and pick html or body based on that it works (body in everything but ie and ffox, html in ie and ffox). The company page still doesn't work some of the time thought - the image doesn't load - any ideas?

Comment: Most of the pages just don't load half the time?