# JQuery scrollTop - cross browser compatibility issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

Yesterday I had an issue with a JQuery scrolling script that worked in Chrome but not in IE and Firefox.  I asked this query ([JQuery scroll() / scrollTop() not working in IE or Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290602/jquery-scroll-scrolltop-not-working-in-ie-or-firefox)) yesterday which I marked as being the correct answer only to realise today that it doesn't work in Chrome anymore!

Can anyone help me get this working on all modern browsers?

HTML

```
<div id="dotted-line">
    <div id="up-arrow">^up</div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
//get window size values (cross browser compatible)
(function(undefined) {
    var container = $("html,body");
    $.windowScrollTop = function(newval) {
        if( newval === undefined) {
            return container.scrollTop();
        }
        else {
            return container.scrollTop(newval);
        }
    }
})();

//draw dotted line on scroll    
$(window).scroll(function(){

    if ($.windowScrollTop() > 10) {
        var pos = $.windowScrollTop();
        $('#dashes').css('height',pos/4);
        $('#footer-dot').css('top',pos/4);
    } else {
        $('#dashes').css('height','6px');
        $('#footer-dot').css('top','-150px');
    }
});
```

Comment: `scrollTop()` will return value of only first macthed element in set `$('html,body')`, that's why it no more works on chrome

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556752/jquery-scrolltop-not-working-on-body-element-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `scrollTop()` will return value of only first matched element in set
>   $('html,body'), that's why it no more works on chrome

I think your best bet would be to use:

```
var container = $(document.scrollingElement || "html");
```

Comment: That now breaks in IE and firefox.

Comment: @LeeTee Which IE/FF version?

Comment: IE11 and Firefox 43.0.1

Comment: Works for me on both, i mean checking for scrollTop() works in FF/IE/chrome browsers.  See example https://jsfiddle.net/wwg01nox/   EDIT: in fact i tested it on IE edge, breaks on IE10

Comment: I see adeneo dupe link, so looks like `var container = $(window)` would be enough

Comment: Ok I got it working with your original solution, maybe I was looking int the wrong place when I thought it had broke in IE & Firefox.  Sorry.  Thanks for your  help.