# countTo script doesn't work in the last version of chrome/firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have a script that counts to a number when i scroll to an element, but it stopped working in Chrome/Firefox for no reason. However it works fine in Edge.

I tried clearing cache and cookies and disabled extensions, but it still doesn't work.

```js
$(function() {
  var oTop = $('.stats').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
    if (pTop > oTop) {
      start_count();
    }
  });
});
var executed = false; // <= variable to false.

function start_count() {


  if (!executed) { // <= make sure it didn't executed before.

    $('.stats h1').countTo({
      onComplete: function() {
        var elementToPrepend = '<span style="margin-left:4px;">+</span>';
        $(elementToPrepend).hide().appendTo(this).fadeIn();

      }
    });

    executed = true; // <= the count() function already executed

  }

}
```

```css
.empty-space {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countto/1.2.0/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
<div class="empty-space">
   scroll down...
</div>
<div class="stats">
   <h1 data-from="200" data-to="2000" data-speed="1750" data-refresh-interval="50">200</h1>
</div>
<div class="empty-space">
</div>
```

Demo link: https://jsfiddle.net/30w9kbfj

**Chrome:** Version 61.0.3163.79 (Official Build) (64-bit).

**Firefox:** Version 55.0.3 (64-bit).

**OS:** Windows 10 64-bit.

If it didn't work for you try using Edge and let me know, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Working in chrome

Comment: @anu whats your chrome's version?

Comment: Its working also in IE 11, FF and chrome

Comment: Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit

Comment: @anu you are using an older version i guess.

Comment: @CodeHacker this is so strange :/ because it doesn't work on my linux laptop too.

Comment: Wht's the latest then? I'm not getting ant updates

Comment: @anu the update [released](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2017/09/stable-channel-update-for-desktop.html) yesterday

Comment: guys any suggestions?

Comment: Works in **Chrome Version 58.0.3029.96 (64-bit)** and **Firefox 55.0.2 (64-bit)**  on **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**.

Comment: @cyrix i'm using Chrome: Version **61.0.3163.79** and Firefox: Version **55.0.3** i'm not sure why no one is using my version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that `Element.scrollTop` got updated in Chrome/Firefox, whatever.

I found a workaround by combining `Element.scrollTop` and `document.scrollingElement.scrollTop` to make it cross-browser.

```
$(document.scrollingElement || "body").scrollTop();
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35317832/7563449).

[Document.scrollingElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/scrollingElement).

[Element.scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop).